# I have an old house. Is there a device I can use to increase wattage so I can use several 1500 watt heaters during winter?

Tags: heater

I have an old house. If I use more than 1500 watts it blows the fuse.

Comment: How about a heat pump.

Comment: You could use a diesel generator exclusively feeding heavy duty circuit.

Comment: simple: put different heaters on different circuits. even a mere 50-amp service should run several heaters.

Comment: Get a heat pump. Depending on temperature and quality of the unit you might get 2-4w (or more) of heat per 1 w of electricity. That'd turn 1500w into 3000-6000w of heating.

Comment: Plug-in space heaters as primary heating is illegal, unsafe and very expensive. The heaters are costly (given how often they fail) and I hardly need to mention the impact on your electric bill.  If you want the electric bill pain, you need to have a pro come in and install some cheap Cadet baseboards that run on 240V - #12 Romex cable will suffice for 3840W of those.  If you are wiser, look for heat pumps - either a mini-split or they make *window unit "A/C" style* heat pumps that can heat.  Look for three 500-watt units.  A 500W heat pump makes more heat than a 1500W space heater.

Answer (score 1):

If your house has a limited electrical capacity and using more than 1500 watts causes the fuse to blow, attempting to increase the wattage by bypassing the electrical limitations can be dangerous. It may result in electrical fires or damage to your electrical system. You can do a load calculation and redesign the whole electrical system of your house accordingly. You can look for a licensed electrical consultant for this job. Also, you can consider alternative methods of heating.